# The scope of a variable(using fork() and wait())

Tags: c++, fork, wait

I'm learning the wait and fork function, I'm trying to print out the Sum of the parent and child process but for some reason the Sum seems to be re-initialized to zero in the parent process, I'm also not sure about the way I implemented the wait function since all the resources I could find online were in c not c++.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int Sum = 0;

void printout()
{
  int id = fork();
  if(id!=0)
  {
    wait(NULL);
  }

  if(id == 0)
  {
    Sum += 2;
  }

  if(id!= 0)
  {
    Sum += 3;
  }
}

int main()
{
    printout();
    std::cout<<Sum<<std::endl;
}
```

I was expecting the output of:

```
5
```

but I get the outpu as:

```
2
3
```

Comment: `fork()` doesn't share global variables with the child. The whole point of `fork()` is that the new process gets a copy of the program's state at that moment. Both variables are zero at that time, so you haven't actually communicated anything between the two.

Comment: From [fork docs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) *"The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces"*. So, `Sum` is not shared after using "fork"

Comment: As to why you get two lines of output, instead of just one as you seemed to expect:  The parent and child run completely independently, so both of them will return to `main` after completing `printout()`, and thus both will execute the output statement.  There is nothing special about the particular function from which `fork()` is called; the system call operates on a machine level and has nothing to do with the way the source code is structured.  (By the way, it's strange to name your function `printout()` when it doesn't print anything.)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're facing is because the `fork()` system call creates a new child process that is an exact copy of the parent process, including its variables and memory. However, the child process and the parent process have separate memory spaces. This means that when you modify the `Sum` variable in the child process, it does not affect the `Sum` variable in the parent process, and vice versa.

In your code, the parent and child processes have their own separate copies of the `Sum` variable, and they are incrementing their respective copies. When you print `Sum` in the `main` function, you are only printing the value of the `Sum` variable in the parent process.

If you want to get the sum of the values modified in both the parent and child processes, you can use inter-process communication (IPC) mechanisms like pipes or shared memory.

For Example using pipes:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int Sum = 0;
    int pipe_fd[2]; // Create a pipe for communication

    if (pipe(pipe_fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    int id = fork();

    if (id == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if (id == 0) { // Child process
        close(pipe_fd[0]); // Close the read end of the pipe in the child process
        int childSum = 2;
        write(pipe_fd[1], &childSum, sizeof(childSum)); // Write childSum to the pipe
        close(pipe_fd[1]); // Close the write end of the pipe in the child process
    } else { // Parent process
        close(pipe_fd[1]); // Close the write end of the pipe in the parent process
        read(pipe_fd[0], &Sum, sizeof(Sum)); // Read the child's value from the pipe
        close(pipe_fd[0]); // Close the read end of the pipe in the parent process
        Sum += 3; // Modify the Sum in the parent process
        wait(NULL);
        std::cout << Sum << std::endl; // Output the final sum
    }

    return 0;
}
```